# Javascript replace for equal symbol

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby

I am getting my response as following

```
var val = {&quot;Type&quot;=&gt;&quot;D&quot;,&quot;Number&quot;=&gt;33&quot;}
```

From above i try to change  like this

```
var MyArray = {"Type": "D", "Number": "33"};


for(key in MyArray)
{
  alert("key " + key
    + " has value "
    + MyArray[key]);
}
```

I tried replace, replace all but those not working. Any suggestions?

Server side code pasted from comments...

```
 new_transfer_header = @params['my_extra_param']
 p new_transfer_header,'------------ ew_transfer_header----------,new_transfer_header.class
 WebView.execute_js("replaceDeliveryWithScanUnit('#{new_transfer_header}')") 

puts result as "{\"Type\"=>\"D\", \"Number\"=>\"33\"}
```

Comment: is `var val =` included in the response? or just the JSON part?

Comment: val is not in the response. I am assigning response to variable val

Comment: can you post the server side code for building this response? i assume you are using some sort of `html_entities`

Comment: {\"Type\"=>\"D\", \"Number\"=>\"33\"} - This is in server side

Comment: what i meant was how it is echoed. the whole code that prints it.

Comment: new_transfer_header = @params['my_extra_param']
    p new_transfer_header,'------------------- new_transfer_header -----------',new_transfer_header.class
      WebView.execute_js("replaceDeliveryWithScanUnit('#{new_transfer_header}')") - I am building like this. The "new_transfer_header" look's like the above comment

Comment: Please edit original question where I've copied your code. Does not look correct to me, but I don't know Ruby.

Answer (score 2):

```
var val = {&quot;Type&quot;=&gt;&quot;D&quot;,&quot;Number&quot;=&gt;33&quot;}
```

Is invalid JavaScript - there is no way to fix it within the same script/script block since it fails parsing.

Likely you need to eliminate extra HTML encoding that somone done for this chunk of script **on the server**.

If it is text received by some AJAX call you should be able to replace `&quot;` and similar values with corresponding characters and than parse with JSON.parse.

Comment: {\"Type\"=>\"D\", \"Number\"=>\"33\"} from backend i am sending like this. It's a string class. Is possible to convert json format

Comment: Consider specifying what language you are using on server, better yet provide server side code in your question (no more than 7 lines).

Comment: new_transfer_header = @params['my_extra_param']
WebView.execute_js("replaceDeliveryWithScanUnit('#new_transfer_header}')")
new_transfer_header look like above. I am using ruby.

Answer (score 0):

you could use string.replace and cal eval on the result I think, but would it be better to get valid json from the server ?