# Handle json in ruby

Tags: ruby, json

In ruby how to convert the follwing into valid json

> "{\"transferType\"=>\"D\", \"accountNumber\"=>\"123\", \"employeeId\"=>\"12\", \"districtNumber\"=>\"15\", \"orderedBy\"=>\"vbcb\", \"department\"=>\"vghghj\", \"po\"=>\"23434\", \"Phone\"=>\"4542433435\", \"Instructions\"=>\"vbvcnvbnb\"}"

The class of above is string. Because Without proper Json conversion i am problem like 
[Javascript replace for equal symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10151803/javascript-replace-for-equal-symbol)

Comment: I sending this from controller to js side. In js side i want to get all key values

Comment: The best thing to do is *not* start from that string, which looks like the `.inspect` output of a Ruby hash. Start with the actual hash and use the JSON library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should make this in to proper JSON format. So replace the **=>** in to **:**
and then try **JSON.load** or **JSON.parse** will work successfully.

```
2.2.3 :015 > data
 => "{\"transferType\"=>\"D\", \"accountNumber\"=>\"123\", \"employeeId\"=>\"12\", \"districtNumber\"=>\"15\", \"orderedBy\"=>\"vbcb\", \"department\"=>\"vghghj\", \"po\"=>\"23434\", \"Phone\"=>\"4542433435\", \"Instructions\"=>\"vbvcnvbnb\"}" 
2.2.3 :016 > JSON.parse(data.gsub("=>", ":"))
 => {"transferType"=>"D", "accountNumber"=>"123", "employeeId"=>"12", "districtNumber"=>"15", "orderedBy"=>"vbcb", "department"=>"vghghj", "po"=>"23434", "Phone"=>"4542433435", "Instructions"=>"vbvcnvbnb"}
```

from the result you can do anything what do you want :)